# How to get only the sub folder names from a S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm having a S3 bucket, which contains many sub folders.
let's say,

```
'test-bucket'
-->'photos'
    -->2020
    -->2019
    -->2018
    ...
```

In the 'test-bucket' there is a sub folder called 'photos' and in the photos folder there may have multiple sub folders.

So i need to loop through photos bucket and get only the photos older than 2 years (ie from 2018). This is my code below using python library boto3.

```
current_year = datetime.datetime.now().year
client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='test-bucket',Prefix = 'photos/'+str(current_year-3),MaxKeys=1000 )
```

But this only returns 2018 data only. Suggest an idea to loop through entire years which are older than 2 years.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Run that loop for 2018, 2019 and 2020. `for year in range(current_year - 3, current_year):` or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain the folder names by using `ListObjects()` while passing a `Delimiter` value. It then returns the list of folders as `CommonPrefixes`.

Here's some sample code:

```py
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
objects = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='my-bucket', Delimiter='/', Prefix ='photos/')

for prefix in objects['CommonPrefixes']:
    print(prefix['Prefix'])
```

Comment: does this even answer op's question? this piece of code only prints out the folders at the very top level. add prefix = 'str' arg to get folders beyond first level